# backbone custom properties for collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

So I'm trying count my models in my collection by the category they have.

This is my code:

```javascript
App.Collections.channls = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model:    App.Models.Channel,
    catCount: new Array(),

    initialize: function() {
      this.bind('add', this.onModelAddedd, this);
    },

    onModelAdded: function( model, collection ) {
         if (this.catCount[model.get('category_id')] == undefined) {
           this.catCount[model.get('category_id')] = 0;
         }
         this.catCount[model.get('category_id')]++;
    },

    returnCount: function() { return this.catCount }
});
```

I initialize this collection a couple of times.

The problem is that when I get the `catCount` property of the collection, the array acts like a global variable. So it didn't only count the models from its own instance of the collection, but the array is counting all the models that are added over *all* the instances of the collection.

Anyone know how to make a property of a collection only count towards its own instance?

Comment: why are you initialize this collection a couple of times?. mean u bind add event multiple times.

Comment: I have data that needs to be seperated but has the same structure ( so the same model and collection )

Comment: you can use same structure by creating multiple instance of model or collection.

Comment: yeah thats what I'm doing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to move catCount to initialize function?

```
initialize: function( ) {
   this.catCount= new Array();
   this.bind( 'add', this.onModelAddedd, this );
}
```

so it will be initialized every new collection instance